# LED is turned on directly after power up without a reason

Tags: led, pic

I am programming a PIC micro-controller to turn on an LED by serial communication. at first the program just works fine. But suddenly, when I power on the micro-controller the LED turns on, and remains on, and if I remove the +ve branch and reinstall it again everything works again fine as it should be. what is the reason for this problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: what is `+ve branch`?

Comment: @jsotola Just a sneaky thought for now, but I think the OP is "lifting a wire" from the (+) power supply and then re-attaching it (wireless protoboard style.) I suspect the I/O pin is latching on power-up, sometimes, due to a poor design (current isn't sufficiently limited to specs, for example, and the LED source voltage is above the MCU rail voltage.) But it's probably good to find out what the OP really means. I'm just randomly guessing.

Comment: Do you have a circuit diagram how you connect the LED to the PIC micro and plus the example code?

Comment: "first the program just works fine. But suddenly, when I power on the micro-controller the LED turns on," ... How could yor program work without starting the controller? Please show your code

Comment: @Mike , I think OP means that his program worked on computer (possibly after compiling code).

Comment: the initial tests showed that the program was successful, but when I added some coding to the program and simulated it, the simulation did not show any problem. However the verification test showed this error, and this was all done without any hardware modifications in the circuit.

Anyway, I have solved this problem by a voltage regulator with some diodes.

Thank you very much guys for your opinions to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe write an answer with an explanation, otherwise this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tended to solve this problem by adding an LM7805 voltage regulator at the entrance of power sources, this solution damped the spikes of the power supply push button.

I also tended to modify the code of the project to the older version. it worked for this moment until i find a better code to replace it with the old part.

Thank you guys for your cooperation to solve this problem with me